# How to enable Right-to-Left in Basket Note

Tags: hebrew, rtl

I'm using basket note for my studies, which is in Hebrew.

With Ubuntu 13.04 and older I could have switched from LtR to RtL easily by clicking <kbd>R Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R Shift</kbd>. It doesn't work anymore...

Any idea on what I should do to return it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, kind of...
If I copy the text to LibreOffice and enable RtL and then copy back to the Basket I get the desired result.

Comment: Well, that's nice work around but not not for lazy one like me :)  . See this solution it may help you too. https://askubuntu.com/questions/522512/switch-text-direction-in-gedit/