# Switch text direction in GEdit

Tags: gedit, text-editor, rtl

I want GEdit to show all paragraphs in right-to-left view. I know that it renders paragraphs starting with rtl characters correctly. But I need paragraphs starting with ltr characters also shown as rtl.

Something like `vim -F` or `set: rl` command in Vim.n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force a paragraph to be RTL by adding Unicode control U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (RLM) to the beginning of the paragraph. Using:

> <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> Then `200f` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

For easy entry, you may have to customize you keyboard layout. See [reference](https://askubuntu.com/q/380776/26246).

There are more Unicode control characters:

- U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (LRM), To do the reverse on a right-to-left environment.
- U+061C ARABIC LETTER MARK (ALM), Note: Most users uses RLM instead which is more general and it works for Arabic scripts too.
- More at [Wikipedia: Bidirectional Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_Text).

**References:**

- [Cannot type “ć” on Hungarian layout](https://askubuntu.com/q/257824/26246)
- [Stabilizing characters like `< >`, `{ }` and `[ ]`](https://askubuntu.com/q/380776/26246)

Comment: Just one thing should be noted: this solution is not suitable if you don't want the text to be modified. using this approach might have side effect in other situations. This solution is not changing GEdit behavior but altering the text. This should be noted and kept in mind while applying this answer.